# If I use open source code with license X, does my code that uses it have be under license X?

Tags: licensing

For example, if I use some open source code that is licensed with an MIT license in my (commercial) project, does my project in turn have to be under the MIT license or do I have to distribute the MIT license or anything like that?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php In general, you need to read the license carefully and follow the rules. With the MIT License, the answer is no, you don't.

Comment: X = MIT.  sorry should have said that in the first place

Comment: Well, I should have figured it out.  MIT wrote X, and X is licensed under the MIT license, after all.  :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the MIT license (similar to the BSD license) is very permissive in this regard. You can mostly do with libraries (and other software) released under this license whatever you want. Just if you bundle code from an MIT-licensed project with your own project, you, as far as I can tell, have to keep the license and copyright header of the affected files in place. For details read the [license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) carefully :-)

The term you are looking for here is "viral". If a license has a viral nature, software A under that license used in software B affects the license of software B. With MIT as with BSD you should be on the safe side. On the other hand, there are some opensource license that are viral or at least have some traits of a viral license.

I'm not a lawyer, though, so it might be better to ask someone dealing with the legal sides of software licensing

Comment: this is what confuses me: "have to keep the license and copyright header of the affected files in place."  If you are taking a snippet of MIT-licensed code into your project, and, if you distribute MIT-license.txt with your app, I think it gives the impression all your software is MIT-licensed.

Comment: unknown: As I read it, it just means that in the *code* you take, you need to keep the license in place (you can't re-license it), it doesn't affect how you license *your* stuff. It just means that if don't make 'substantial' changes to the MIT-Licensed code, it still retains it's original license. But if it's of great concern, you DO need to talk to a laywer. Try the EFF. They will be more detailed information how to deal with it.

Comment: These comments demonstrate the importance of getting legal advice - if you're hoping to sell a product that uses OSS software, you should consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the text of the license.  In the case of the MIT license, the text of the license reads (emphasis mine):

> Copyright (c) [year] [copyright holders]
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person  obtaining a
>   copy of this software and associated
>   documentation  files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software without 
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use,  copy,
>   **modify**, **merge**, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, **and/or sell**  copies of the
>   Software, and to permit persons to
>   whom the  Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following 
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be  included
>   in all copies or substantial portions
>   of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS",
>   WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,  EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO THE WARRANTIES  OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND 
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT  HOLDERS BE
>   LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY,  WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING 
>   FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR  OTHER DEALINGS
>   IN THE SOFTWARE.

If you're still unsure of how that affects you, you should really ask a lawyer, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the license, if you modify the code, if your code is derivative, etc. The license will tell you but you do have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the conditions imposed by the license, so you have to read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier comment is spot on for MIT license. In general, your best bet when mixing proprietary and OSS code is to 1) read the specific license, 2) consult a lawyer, 3) comply with the license. Anything else is asking for trouble